# Error when loading shapefiles into IBM Bluemix dashDB

Tags: shapefile, dashdb

I am running into the following error when loading my shapefiles data locally into [dashDB](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/dashdb/)

[image: Error when loading]

The shapefiles in my zipped file are the following:

[image: Shape files]

Anyone has experience doing this with dashDB?

**UPDATE**

I downloaded a separate dataset with the following files:

[image: Files in zip folder]

and I am still running into the same error message...

Answer (score 1):

Document for loading geospatial data into dashDB is at

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/learn_how/loaddata_gsdata.html

> The source file must be a compressed file in one of the following
>   formats:
>
> ```
> tar.gz
> tar
> zip
> ```
>
> This file must include a shapefile set that contains the following
>   files:  [.shp .shx .dbf .prj]

Your zip is missing .prj which is documented to be compulsory.

Comment: I downloaded a different set of files and included the .shp, .shx, .dbf, .prf, and I now have the following error: "The load process failed because the source file has an unknown file format. Select a source file that has a supported format. Error code: 2011"

Comment: I am still getting the same error despite having the files [.shp .shx .dbf .prj] in a zip folder.